# How to use newtonsoft.json nested

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Im trying to parse a JSON with Newtonsoft.JSON package.

```
string jsonData =
 "{\"name\":\"olga\",\"tokenmode\":\"bearer\",\"expires\":9483,\"refresh\":\"{\\\"Id\\\":\\\"alla-ieih-8493j-2455d\\\",\\\"Id\\\":\\\"94094-3838485-kdooj4u\\\"}\",\"status\":\"10\",\"namestatus\":\"5\"}";


 dynamic aa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);

var name = aa.name.tostring(); //Outputs olga

var id = aa.refresh.Id.ToString(); //Gives error
```

Question is how can i access the Id data?

Comment: Is `refresh`supposed to be a inline json? If yes, it is not correct and you can get Id more specifically you get the last Id. Because `Id` is a duplicate key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to add a

```
dynamic refresh = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(aa.refresh.ToString());
```

Comment: it doesn't need to be dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Create a class:

```
class Player
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Elapsed { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Player(Guid id, string name, TimeSpan elapsed)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Elapsed = elapsed;
    }
    public Player(string name, TimeSpan elapsed)
    {
        this.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Name = name;
        this.Elapsed = elapsed;
    }
}
```

Ask for object:

```
Player player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(jsonstring);
```

Ask for list of objects:

```
List<Player> players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(jsonstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:

```
var id = aa.refresh[0].Id.ToString();
```

Comment: I tested this before, and it throws {"Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue."}